# ZendFramework 2: No database adapter present

Tags: zend-framework2, adapter, global

I have this class:

```
<?php
class RegisterFilter extends InputFilter
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->add(array(
            'name'       => 'email1',
            'required'   => true,
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name'    => 'EmailAddress',
                    'options' => array(
                        'domain' => true,
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                      'name'    => 'Identical',
                      'options' => array(
                        'token' => 'email2',
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                      'name'    => 'Db\NoRecordExists',
                      'options' => array(
                        'table' => 'user',
                        'field' => 'email',
                        'messages' => array(
                            'recordFound'   => "Email already exist ... ! <br>",  
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ));
    }
}
?>
```

I get this error: No database adapter present. Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good if you'd read [the documentation about `Zend\Validator\Db\Record*`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.validator.set.html#db-recordexists-and-db-norecordexists). The given error message means exactly what it said. You don't provide a DB-Adapter inside the Validator.

**From the DOCs:**

```
$validator = new Zend\Validator\Db\RecordExists(
    array(
        'table'   => 'users',
        'field'   => 'emailaddress',
        'adapter' => $dbAdapter
    )
);
```

If you want to find out how to get the DB-Adapter into your Form, i have written [a Blog Article](http://samminds.com/2013/03/zendformelementselect-and-database-values/) about said topic.

Comment: What is the value of $dbAdapter. Also at http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.validator.db.html they use it differently.

Comment: Also, can I set the validator for the form. I was able to set a filter. Wondering if it is the same process.

Comment: @EliMiller Yes they use it differently, but the schema is still identical. $dbAdapter should be like Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter, it has to be an AdapterInterface ;) Filter/Validators are pretty much the same story.